# I want to understand what will happen each phase of maven when i invoke the maven clean install

Tags: java, maven

I want to understand what will happen when i invoke the maven clean install.

More Description about my Question :

Maven contains the different build life cycle and each life cycle contains the different phases . I want to understand whats going on each phase.

for example scanning the project(What it will scans in the project),creation of target folder, filtering resources ,creation of the source folder.. etc .

All these things i have found while going through the logs but i can't see any in-detail information.( for example how many folders maven creates and order of creation , what files it will filter...)

i want to see all these internals to get more understanding on Maven each phase

I did googled but i didn't find any thing how to get this more info .

Please help me getting this info.

Answer (score 1):

There's a command line option `-X` that would get you out, here's what it can do:

> The -X option will print an overwhelming amount of debugging log messages to the output. This option is primarily used by Maven developers and by Maven plugin developers to diagnose problems with Maven code during development. This -X option is also very useful if you are attempting to diagnose a difficult problem with a dependency or a classpath.

`mvn clean install -X`

Reference:
http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html

Comment: Thank q Chin ,                                                                                                        Is there any other option i can get the log for each specific phase ?

Comment: if i want to get more info on each phase I have to run each phase individually                                                                                                             lilke mvn clean -X,mvn validate -X ..etc rty ?

Comment: you want to log the output?  in Windows, you can type `mvn clean install -X > log.txt`  to save it to disk.

Comment: I have tried to use mvn validate -X but getting the below issue [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are:

Comment: i want debug each phase individually ?

Comment: No, you can just run `mvn clean validate -X` if you like.

Comment: If you're using IDE like *Eclipse*  `mvn` is superfluous.

Comment: I have tried but still same issue which ever i mentioned earlier.BTW what the difference between mvn clean  validate -X and mvn validate -X .According to maven we can run the phases with out clean .please correct me some thing i miss understood

Comment: [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: , ... -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException: Unknown lifecycle phase "mvn". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122558/discussion-between-jerry-chin-and-maddy).